# How to detect the Ms-Access database exceeds the max size using c sharp

Tags: c#, ms-access, size, max

I have an Ms-Access database (2003) and I have noticed that it gives OledbException: Invalid Argument when the database size exceeds 2GB (Which is the maximum size of the database).

Is there anyway of detecting that this exception was thrown exactly due the to the reason that database has exceeded its maximum size.(I need it to backup the database then)...

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you need to backup _before_ it explodes.

Comment: That would be better, and can you pls tell me how to do that???

Comment: If you can get the filepath, FileInfo can tell you the length.

Comment: Yeah, that means I should check it everytime I insert data to database... isn t it??? Isn t there any better solution for this???

Comment: A better solution? sure. Plenty of real databases on the market.

Comment: :) yeah, but we we need to use Ms-Access and there s a rear chance of exceeding the limit... what we want is to handle that situation if occurs...

Comment: If/When it occurs you're already dead. You have to write a preventive algo yourself.

Comment: @Dulini Atapattu - The simple solution?  Upgrade your Access 2003 database to a x64 operating system using Access 2010.  The 2GB limit is a limitation of a 32-application which if your running Office 2003 is exactly that.  Which means you likely are not using a x64 bit operating system at all.

Comment: @ Henk Holterman: Ok... Thanks a lot for information...

Comment: @ Ramhound: Yeah, that info s true and thanks Ramhound...

Comment: The 2GB limit is imposed by Access, not the operating system.  Running Access under 64 bit Windows will **not** allow you to create/use Access database files larger than 2GB.

Comment: It's not imposed by Access, but by the Jet/ACE database engine. Access can work with data stores much larger than 2GBs if you use a database engine that supports it (such as SQL Server).

Comment: If you're approaching the 2GB limit, then Access/Jet/ACE is simply not an appropriate data store for your application. Indeed, I'd say that any Access app where you're flirting with 1GB of data should be upsized to a different back end.

Comment: Thanks to all for providing valuable information....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
constant long TWO_G = (2*1024*1024*1024); 
constant long MARGIN = (8 * 1024 * 1024); 
string pathToMonsterMdb = "monster.mdb";
FileInfo mdb = new FileInfo(pathToMonsterMdb);
long len = mdb.Length;
if (len > (TWO_G - MARGIN) {
   /* File's getting close to max size.  Deal with it. */
}
```

Of course, the real question is actually what to do about the problem.  With a data base this size you probably want to move to a more robust table server.

If you set MARGIN big enough you can run this less often than after every single insert.